# Xcode 5.1.1: Undefined symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am  Using the Symbollic c++ library . My app run well on Xcode simulator as well as other devices but there is some problem while making the build .I am getting the following Errors while i am building the app:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

"Number<double>::Number(double const&)", referenced from:

List item  Log::simplify() const in functions.o    

Power::simplify() const in functions.o    
"Number<int>::Number(int const&)", referenced from:    
Product::simplify() const in product.o    
operator+(Symbolic const&, int const&) in symbolicc++.o    
operator-(Symbolic const&) in symbolicc++.o    
operator/(Symbolic const&, Symbolic const&) in symbolicc++.o    
sqrt(Symbolic const&) in symbolicc++.o    
Symbolic zero<Symbolic>(Symbolic) in symbolicc++.o    
Sum::simplify() const in sum.o
    ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7  
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have already done the following Things:

1. Set the c++ language Dialect : GNU++11[-std=gnu++11]
2. set c++ standard Library : libstd++(GNU standard library)
3. valid Architecture : armv7 armv7s
4. Provisional Profile is also set
5. set ObjC as other linker flags
6. added assists framework also

Comment: Generally this means that the library doesn't have the `armv7` architecture included.  You can confirm by running the `file` command on the static library from the command line.

Comment: Or `lipo -info` <library-name>.

Comment: remove armv7 and armv7s and add again

Comment: @vishnu I have removed armv7 armv7s and add again but the problem remain the same

Comment: @PhillipMills When i run the lipo -info SymbolliccC++3  The this give the following output that I don't understand                    Vipins-Mac-mini:SymbolicC++3-3.35-vc vipinyadav$ lipo -info SymbolicC++3/
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode 5.1.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't map input file: SymbolicC++3/ (Invalid argument)

Comment: Sounds like the file name you gave it is wrong.  Is that the actual library?  Maybe give it a full path name....

Comment: @PhillipMills File name is correct and I have already gave the complete path of the library

Comment: No, a command that used the complete path to a library would be something like "lipo -info /Library/Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/QtSql" as an example.